# How to use Array.reduce()?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JSON response like below:

```
[
{"name": "a", "data": [{"value":10,"id":1},{"value":20,"id":2}],
{"name": "b", "data": [{"value":10,"id":1},{"value":20,"id":2}],
{"name": "c", "data": [{"value":10,"id":1},{"value":20,"id":2}],
{"name": "d", "data": [{"value":10,"id":1},{"value":20,"id":2}],
{"name": "e", "data": [{"value":10,"id":1},{"value":20,"id":2}],
]
```

How to sum each "value" inside each element of data (column wise) and get the result like:

```
[{"name": "something", "data":[{"value":50,"id":1},{"value":100,"id":2}]
```

How to use array.reduce() for this or is there any other method to achieve the above result?

Comment: Your JSON is invalid.

Comment: does `data` have always the same `id` on the same index?

Comment: You spec is not clear. We can understand how to reduce values by id, but your given suggested result is not clear about the "name" key... Do you want to *reduce* the names?

Comment: the final result you want is the some of values based on their id's?? so you should look for `[{"value":50,"id":1},{"value":100,"id":2}]` not for name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out the following logic.

```
var series = [{"name": "a", "data": [{"value":10,"id":1},{"value":20,"id":2}]}, ... , ....]

var resultSeries = series.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    var result = {
        name: ‘Something’,
        data: []
    };
    var dataArray = acc.data.map((el, i) => {
        var curData = cur.data[i] || {};
        var sum = (el.value || 0) + (curData.value || 0);
        return {
            value: sum
        }
    });
    result.data = dataArray ;
    return result;
})
```

now `resultSeries` will hold

```
[{"name": "something", "data":[{"value":50,"id":1},{"value":100,"id":2}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object as hash table for the `id` and sum the values.

```js
var array = [{ name: "a", data: [{ value: 10, id: 1 }, { value: 20, id: 2 }] }, { name: "b", data: [{ value: 10, id: 1 }, { value: 20, id: 2 }] }, { name: "c", data: [{ value: 10, id: 1 }, { value: 20, id: 2 }] }, { name: "d", data: [{ value: 10, id: 1 }, { value: 20, id: 2 }] }, { name: "e", data: [{ value: 10, id: 1 }, { value: 20, id: 2 }] }],
    result = { name: 'something', data: Object.values(array.reduce((r, { data }) => {
        data.forEach(({ value, id }) => {
            r[id] = r[id] || { value: 0, id };
            r[id].value += value;
        });
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null))) };

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<script>
 var numbers = [
{"name": "a", "data": [{"value":10,"id":1},{"value":20,"id":2}]},
{"name": "b", "data": [{"value":10,"id":1},{"value":20,"id":2}]},
{"name": "c", "data": [{"value":10,"id":1},{"value":20,"id":2}]},
{"name": "d", "data": [{"value":10,"id":1},{"value":20,"id":2}]},
{"name": "e", "data": [{"value":10,"id":1},{"value":20,"id":2}]},
];

function getSum(total, val) {
  total.data[0].value = total.data[0].value + val.data[0].value;
  total.data[1].value = total.data[1].value + val.data[1].value;
  return total;
 }
function myFunction(item) {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
  JSON.stringify(numbers.reduce(getSum));
}
```

This prints

```
Sum of numbers in array: {"name":"a","data":[{"value":50,"id":1},{"value":100,"id":2}]}
```

The code just adds the values on each iteration and updates the existing value.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var arr =[{"name": "a", "data": [{"value":10,"id":1},{"value":20,"id":2}]},{"name": "b", "data": [{"value":10,"id":1},{"value":20,"id":2}]},{"name": "c", "data": [{"value":10,"id":1},{"value":20,"id":2}]},{"name": "d", "data": [{"value":10,"id":1},{"value":20,"id":2}]},{"name": "e", "data": [{"value":10,"id":1},{"value":20,"id":2}]}];

var result = {
   "name" : "something",
   "data" : arr.reduce((a,c) => { // reduces/merges 2 records of arr
      a.data.map((v, i) => { // add values for the 2 records (column wise)
        v.value = v.value + c.data[i].value;
        return v;
      });
      return a;
   })
};
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your JSON data looks like what I've used in the below snippet. You could do this:

```js
    a = [
    {"name": "a", "data": [{"value":10,"id":1},{"value":20,"id":2}]},
    {"name": "b", "data": [{"value":10,"id":1},{"value":20,"id":2}]},
    {"name": "c", "data": [{"value":10,"id":1},{"value":20,"id":2}]},
    {"name": "d", "data": [{"value":10,"id":1},{"value":20,"id":2}]},
    {"name": "e", "data": [{"value":10,"id":1},{"value":20,"id":2}]},
    ]
    
    let reducer = (accumulator, currValue) => {
            accumulator.name = "something";
         for (let i = 0; i < accumulator.data.length; i++) {
           accumulator.data[i].value += currValue.data[i].value;
            }
            return accumulator
        };

    // This will give the result you want:

    console.log(a.reduce(reducer));
```

The result will be:

```
{"name":"something","data":[{"value":50,"id":1},{"value":100,"id":2}]}
```